# React-dnd not working in Cordova on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I'm using the react-dnd-touch-backend.

I'm able to get my DragSources to drag correctly, but the DropTargets don't accept them (or react to being dragged over).

The application only uses one wrapper component for each role (DragSource and DropTarget). I have also defined a custom drag layer. The drag/drop worked fine before adding the custom drag layer except my DragSources were invisible on iOS (which is why I added the drag layer in the first place), but now I can see the DragSources, but the DropTargets don't work.

Any help is much appreciated.

DragSource:

```
import React from "react";
import cn from "util/cn";
import {isCordova} from "util/detect-platform";
import {DragSource} from "react-dnd";
import {getEmptyImage} from "react-dnd-html5-backend";

require("./style.scss");

const TYPE = "DRAG-CONTAINER";

const source = {
  beginDrag({value, left, top, children, DragPreviewComponent}) {
    return {value, left, top, children, DragPreviewComponent};
  }
};

function collect(connect, monitor) {
  return {
    connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
    connectDragPreview: connect.dragPreview(),
    isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
  };
}

function getStyles(props) {
  const {left, top, isDragging} = props;
  const transform = `translate3d(${left}px, ${top}px, 0)`;

  return {
    transform: transform,
    WebkitTransform: transform,
    opacity: isDragging ? 0 : 1
  };
}

@DragSource(TYPE, source, collect)
export default class DragContainer extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    value: React.PropTypes.any
  };
  static defaultProps = {style: {}};

  componentDidMount() {
    if(!isCordova()) {
      this.props.connectDragPreview(getEmptyImage(), {
        captureDraggingState: true
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {className, isDragging, connectDragSource, style} = this.props;
    const classNames = cn(
      "Drag-container",
      isDragging ? "Drag-container--dragging" : null,
      className
    );

    return connectDragSource(
      <div {...this.props} className={classNames} value={null} style={{...style, ...getStyles(this.props)}}/>
    );
  }
}
```

DropTarget:

```
import React from "react";
import {DropTarget} from "react-dnd";
import cn from "util/cn";
require("./style.scss");

const TYPE = "DRAG-CONTAINER";

const target = {
  drop(props, monitor) {
    const {onDrop} = props;
    const {value} = (monitor.getItem() || {value: null});

    if(typeof onDrop === "function") {
      setTimeout(() => onDrop(value), 100);
    }
  }
};

function collect(connect, monitor) {
  return {
    connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
    isOver: monitor.isOver()
  };
}

@DropTarget(TYPE, target, collect)
export default class DropContainer extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    onDrop: React.PropTypes.func
  };

  render() {
    const {connectDropTarget, isOver, className} = this.props;
    const classNames = cn("Drop-container", isOver ? "Drop-container--over" : null, className);

    return connectDropTarget(
      <div {...this.props} className={classNames} onDrop={null} onDragEnter={null} onDragExit={null}/>
    );
  }
}
```

Custom Drag Layer:

```
import React from "react";
import {DragLayer} from "react-dnd";

const layerStyles = {
  position: "fixed",
  pointerEvents: "none",
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%",
  zIndex: 100,
  left: 0,
  top: 0
};

function getItemStyles(props) {
  const { initialOffset, currentOffset } = props;
  if (!initialOffset || !currentOffset) {
    return {
      display: 'none'
    };
  }

  let { x, y } = currentOffset;

  if (props.snapToGrid) {
    x -= initialOffset.x;
    y -= initialOffset.y;
    [x, y] = snapToGrid(x, y);
    x += initialOffset.x;
    y += initialOffset.y;
  }

  const transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`;
  return {
    transform: transform,
    WebkitTransform: transform
  };
}

@DragLayer(monitor => ({
  item: monitor.getItem(),
  itemType: monitor.getItemType(),
  initialOffset: monitor.getInitialSourceClientOffset(),
  currentOffset: monitor.getSourceClientOffset(),
  isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
}))
export default class CustomDragLayer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {item, itemType, isDragging} = this.props;
    if (!isDragging || !item) return null;
    const {DragPreviewComponent} = item;
    if(!DragPreviewComponent) return null;
    return (
      <div style={layerStyles}>
        <div style={getItemStyles(this.props)}>
          <DragPreviewComponent {...item}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was this issue in the react-dnd-touch-backend library:
https://github.com/yahoo/react-dnd-touch-backend/issues/34

Rolling back to version 0.2.7 fixed the issue.